# Can I use Sencha FieldLabel tag to put label and text field in reverse order?

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I've made layout with simple gwt, but now I want to make label and text field using gxt 3.0.1.
Gxt provides FieldLabel field. Label on the left than TextField on the right. 
Can I make it to be, text field than label on right side of the text field.

Current code is    `

```
<g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="hpOne" width="1">    
  <g:Cell verticalAlignment="ALIGN_MIDDLE">         
    <form:FieldLabel text="{message.lblTestGroupName}" ui:field="lblTestGroupName">    
      <form:widget>      
        <form:TextField ui:field="tbTestGroupName"/>      
      </form:widget>      
    </form:FieldLabel>    
  </g:Cell>      
 </g:HorizontalPanel>

  `
```

Comment: Apparently this behaviour is [not available](http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/3/com/sencha/gxt/widget/core/client/form/FormPanel.LabelAlign.html) in GXT. That's a pity because it *is* implemented in [ExtJS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.FormPanel-cfg-labelAlign).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if we are on the same plate, but please try this:

```
<g:HorizontalPanel ui:field="hpOne" width="1">
     <form:TextField ui:field="tbTestGroupName" />   
     <form:FieldLabel text="{message.lblTestGroupName}" ui:field="lblTestGroupName" />
</g:HorizontalPanel>
```

Lemme know if you are looking for this.

Comment: Well, now I'm not sure what did I try and failed but this worked fine. Thanks!
There's a lot for me to discover about Sencha.

Comment: Well, sencha is tricky sometimes! It takes a little time to get accustomed with it! Great that it works!